# Training a neural network with post-processed data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I want to fit a large number of functions over a vector space with a neural network. I have a particular architecture in mind, which is naturally broken into two parts: the first part consists of simple neural network operations, such as dense linear layers. The second part takes the output of the first and applies some elementary functions to cast the data in a particular form. It is on this fully post-processed data that I want to train the network parameters present in the first part of the neural network.

Is it possible to take the output of the network, perform these manipulations, and then save that as the output which the network is trained on?

This probably sounds convoluted, but my reason for doing this is that the post-processing functions are best written in terms of functions that aren't supported by the built-in layers of Mathematica. In particular, these functions are complex-valued, so it is simplest to use complex numbers for these intermediate steps and then rewrite those numbers as real 2-component vectors.

Thanks!